# Why does this program crash when a dynamically allocated 2D array receive input?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm taking input from a user to continue with my program. Everything runs perfectly fine until I attempt to input a string into the 2D array, cityName. As soon as I input the string the program crashes.

```
//dynamically allocate memory for user input (integers)
int *xOfCity = calloc(numOfCities, sizeof(int));
int *yOfCity = calloc(numOfCities, sizeof(int));

//dynamically allocate memory for user input (city names)
char **cityName = (char **) calloc(numOfCities, sizeof(char *));
for (int i = 0; i < numOfCities; i++)
    cityName[i] = (char *) calloc(CITY_NAME + 1, sizeof(char));

int dxOfFront, dyOfFront;

//read in data from user
for (int i = 0; i < numOfCities; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &xOfCity[i]);
    if (xOfCity[i] > MAX_GRAPH || xOfCity[i] < MIN_GRAPH)
        return ERROR;
    scanf("%d", &yOfCity[i]);
    if (yOfCity[i] > MAX_GRAPH || yOfCity[i] < MIN_GRAPH)
        return ERROR;
    for (int j = 0; j < CITY_NAME; j++) 
        scanf("%s", cityName[i][j]);
}
```

To be sure that the 2D array was the problem I commented it out and ran the program only taking the integers as inputs, and the program ran fine. I tried allocating the array in a different way, but that didn't seem to work either.

Why would my program crash upon entering a string?

Comment: `cityName[i][j]` is a `char`. `%s` expects a `char*`. Your compiler should warn you about that, so if it didn’t, you should look up how to enable warnings on your compiler. (Also, `scanf("%s")` is hard to use correctly; consider `fgets`.)

Comment: Instead of all this mess, just use `struct city { int x; int y; char name[CITY_NAME + 1]; }` and you do not have **any of these problems**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important here to keep track of your pointer dereferences.

You start with a char**, and you access it after dereferencing it twice - that is, the two indexes, i and j. When you access cityName[i][j], you're not referencing the char*, you're actually passing the value of the first character itself. That means your program is using a character as a pointer!

You'd be better simply doing:

```
scanf("%s",cityName[i]);
```

The j is not necessary.

Comment: The loop around that `scanf()` is also unnecessary.  An alternative, but probably less desirable, option is to use `scanf("%c", &cityName[i][j]);` to read exactly the maximum number of characters for a city name.  Requiring users to count characters themselves is nasty.  But `%s` won't include blanks in the city name — no opportunity to enter "New York" or "San Francisco", for example.